# Is there an Emergency Rescue Disc (ERD) that allows for slipstreaming SATA drivers?

Tags: sata, password-recovery, windows

I have a computer at work that was baselined with the DISA Gold Disc, to include disabling the built-in admin account and setting its password to something unknown. So, while trying to use the repair console, I can't use it without the password (another Gold Disc setting).

However, my ERD does not have the proper SATA drivers to "see" this drive. And, since I know I'm going to need this soft of disc in the future anyway, I thought I'd ask: Does anyone know of an ER disc that allows one to slipstream the drivers, a la nLite?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[You can with any winPE based boot disk.](http://www.google.com/search?q=put+drivers+on+winpe&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a)  [The Ultimate Boot CD for Windows](http://www.ubcd4win.com/) is a personal favorite.

Comment: +1 and accepted. I ended up using the UBCD -- worked like a champ.

Answer (score 1):

how about, i have used systinternals, with the f6 option and usb floppy disk with the sata drivers on it.

Answer (score 1):

See http://www.ratsauce.co.uk/notablog/WinPECD.asp for my walkthrough of making a WinPE boot CD. You can include drivers in the CD, just as for BartPE, but you can also load them from the command line after booting from the CD. See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766220(WS.10).aspx for details.

NB some drivers require a reboot to start, and the drvload comamnd will simply ignore these. You'll need to try out your drivers and see.

JR